# Facebook Login for Android version approved by Facebook Developer. Is it also applied for iOS version?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

our 'Facebook Login' for android version already approved by Facebook Developer. Is it also applied for iOS version? or I should submit another 'Facebook Login' permission for iOS version? Thank you for your help

Comment: I think credentials are always same. whether it is ios or android. Before posting here why don't you try first?

Comment: Have you tried it before asking question?